# How to create packages (folders) in an Eclipse project via plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I try to develop a small plugin for Eclipse to create several Java files in several folders (packages) as a starting point for a new module of a larger software.

I've tried to use an `IFile` object like this:

```
final IFile file = container.getFile(new Path(myFileName));
...
file.create(stream, true, monitor);
```

That works as long as all folders on the path to the file exists. But it does not create any missing folders (new packages) but throws a "resource not exists" exception.

I could not find any way to do this by `IResource` or `IWorkspace` objects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Personally, I use a small method which recursively creates all of the folders, something like:

```
IFile file = project.getFile(newPath);

prepare((IFolder) file.getParent());
```

and then the method

```
public void prepare(IFolder folder) {
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        prepare((IFolder) folder.getParent())
        folder.create(false, false, null);
    }
}
```

This works well for me.

Comment: I just don't came across the IFolder Interface - so thank's a lot!

Comment: I also had to check the type of the parent container like this: `if (folder.getParent() instanceof IFolder) prepare...`. Otherwise, the last call to `getParent` would return an `IProject` and the subsequent cast would cause a `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this does not answer your question, but may I suggest you take a look at [Maven Archetypes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html) ? This way, you could create project templates with the desired directory structure and boilerplate files, in a configurable and non Eclipse-dependant way.