# Creating a package under source folder when developing an eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am developing an Eclipse wizard that will be used for creating a project. I can create the folder hieararchy but I cannot create a package under "src" folder. I found this answer [How to create packages (folders) in an Eclipse project via plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606547/how-to-create-packages-folders-in-an-eclipse-project-via-plugin) here. However, it does not solve my problem. When I create a folder under "src" folder, eclipse does not recognize it as a package. How can I do this?

Comment: How do you know that Eclipse does't recognize the folders as packages?  Have you put a java file in one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using JDT API as below.

```
private void createPackage(IProject project) throws JavaModelException {
   IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create(project);
   IFolder folder = project.getFolder("src");
   // folder.create(true, true, null);
   IPackageFragmentRoot srcFolder = javaProject
       .getPackageFragmentRoot(folder);
   IPackageFragment fragment = srcFolder.createPackageFragment(project.getName(), true, null);
}
```

for more help please access this [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJDT/article.html#jdt_javamodel)